# Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() On host running 5.4.x

Tags: php, mysql

This function works fine in my test envioroment. But returns this error when i try it on my webhost.`Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()`

I know that you need the mysqlnd driver for this. But it is automatically supported at version 5.4.x [Source](http://tapify.nl/php/test.php). But my host has even has a newer version of PHP installed. So i dont understand why it doesn't work.

```
Test environment:
PHP: 5.4.12 
MySQL: 5.6.12

Webhost (doesnt work):
PHP: 5.4.37
MySQL: 5.5.42-cll
```

How do i solve this problem? Is there some kind of manually installing the mysqlnd drivers? Or has it something to do with the MySQL version.

Edit: 
I put a test file in my webhost and it appears that the `get_result()` function is not available.

```
<?php
$hasMySQL = false;
$hasMySQLi = false;
$withMySQLnd = false;

if (function_exists('mysql_connect')) {
    $hasMySQL = true;
    $sentence.= "(Deprecated) MySQL <b>is installed</b> ";
} else 
    $sentence.= "(Deprecated) MySQL <b>is not</b> installed ";

if (function_exists('mysqli_connect')) {
    $hasMySQLi = true;
    $sentence.= "and the new (improved) MySQL <b>is installed</b>. ";
} else
    $sentence.= "and the new (improved) MySQL <b>is not installed</b>. ";

if (function_exists('mysqli_fetch_all')) {
    $withMySQLnd = true;
    $sentence.= "This server is using MySQLnd as the driver.";
} else
    $sentence.= "This server is using libmysqlclient as the driver.";

echo $sentence . "<br>";


$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
if (strpos($db->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CLIENT_VERSION), 'mysqlnd') !== false) {
    echo 'PDO MySQLnd enabled!'. "<br>";
}
else {
    echo 'Not enabled'. "<br>";

}

if (function_exists('get_result')){
    echo "get result() works". "<br>";
}
else {
    echo "nope result() doesnt work". "<br>";
}

phpinfo();


$arr = get_defined_functions();

print_r($arr);
```

You can see the result here: [Test page on my host](http://tapify.nl/php/test.php)

I am going to contact my Hosting provider. But i wonder if there's another solution/ workaround

Edit:
So my Hosting provider is not able to help me. They dont want to change the mysqli server just for me. 
So i switched to PDO instead of MySQLi, Which kinda sucks because i have to rewrite a lot :(.

Comment: The manual may indicate that `mysqlnd` is the default, but that doesn't mean your ISP has compiled their installation that way. My experience is that `mysqlnd` generally is __not__ installed. `phpinfo()` should tell you.

Comment: I just did phpinfo(). But mysqlnd is installed on the server. Could it have someting to do with the mysql version?

Comment: So i contacted my Hosting provider, they said they wont be able to change the mysqli server. As a solution i switched to PDO.

Comment: In the last `if` statement, u have checked with `if(function_exists('get_result'))`; I think u should check with `if(function_exists('mysqli_stmt_get_result'))`. BTW, I m also a frustrated developer with this strange *feature* - mysqlnd is loaded/enabled and still getting the error of undefined mysqli_stmt::get_result() function!

Answer (score -1):

Check your php.ini. You need to have the mysqli dll enabled

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Comment: Irrelevant. If the `mysqli` module was not installed the code wouldn't get as far as it does. This snippet is also only appropriate for a Windows system. Most ISPs run PHP on a Linux box.